# django-tenants TypeError: argument of type 'TenantQueryset' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, postgresql, schema, multi-tenant

i've made a system for hotels , i want to give it to several hotels with the same base code , i have used [django-tenant-schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and this is my `SHARED_APP`  and `TENANT_APP` but when i try `python manage.py migrate_schemas --shared` it only creates my shared apps list and when i try either  `manage.py migrate_schemas --tenant` or  `manage.py migrate_schemas` it raise this error

> if public_schema_name in tenants:
> TypeError: argument of type 'TenantQueryset' is not iterable

this is my settings.py

```
SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'users',
    'rosetta',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'import_export',

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'rooms',
    'vistors',
    'booking',
    'costs',
    'payments',
    'cancel',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]
TENANT_MODEL= "rooms.Hotel"

#db engine 
'ENGINE': 'tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',
```

my models.py

```
class Hotel(TenantMixin):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hotel_name

class Room(models.Model):
    room_no = models.IntegerField()
    #others
```

and i have more models but all of them inherited from `models.Model` ,in the `public` schema it only created tables for `SHARED_APP` apps , `TENANT_APP` not created
**django version 2.2**
**db : postgresql** is there something else i have to change or is'nt there another way to achieve that please

Comment: If possible then could you please share your full settings file?

Comment: @Sabil here you go https://dpaste.com/3UPC7HH54

Comment: @Sabil is there any chance to fix please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't setup django tenant properly
These are some few corrections

1. From the settings.py file there should be only the shared and tenant app... And the installed app consist of the shared and tenant app
2. Your tenant apps doesn't have some important apps like the content types ...

There should be other errors, so I think you should go through these:

1. Just checked your settings.py. You can follow this video ( https://youtu.be/QU70PbJuAUo )
2. Your tenant apps lacks some vital apps which you can reference here https://github.com/Academy-Omen/saasy-blog

Also make sure you can successfully connect your project to a PostgresSQL database before setting up django tenant.

Comment: It's great that you are sharing the links, but could you describe the relevant points in the body of the answer? Links can go bad...

Comment: `TENANT_MODEL` should be `rooms.Hotel` model ? right?

Comment: @Peng can we provide different logo for different tenants ? the logo will show in main.html ?

Comment: Yes you can provide different logos, you can save the logo as an image field in your tenant model and load it per tenant

Comment: @PengBorisAkebuon but how to load it into the template , im not sure how to call back the image ?!